# Is there a simple way to remove the thick gray frame around the Dash menu?

Tags: unity, themes, unity-dash

I'm referring to the frame seen here:

[image]

Is there an easy way to get rid of it? I don't like it and it doesn't really match the rest of the look that I'm going for with all the theming I'm doing. I've tried simply altering the files in `/usr/share/unity/icons`, but when I set them all to blank images with alpha 0 (which worked to remove the square behind icons in the launcher) the frame was replaced by a thick black border that was even worse than the original. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can always fullscreen the dash by clicking the maximize button in the top left, which will remove the grey border.

Answer (score -1):

You could use settings to alter it to be transparent,  and under settings to go to desktop, and there you can make it transparent, and you first have to from the terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and write in /usr/share/unity/icons this transparency=10, and it might work fine this way.